# Crypto.Util import error in firebase_helper.py when deploying to Google App Flexible Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, firebase

I have been working to deploy the [Authenticating Users on App Engine Using Firebase](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/authenticating-users-firebase-appengine) tutorial, and can successfully deploy this to my local machine.

As I wish to test some python modules that don't run on the standard Google App Engine, I have now tried to deploy this to the Flexible Environment via this setting in app.yaml

```
vm: true
```

the frontend deploys fine to the flexible app engine, but the backend throws an error during the import of firebase_helper.py. Specifically, it is choking on this line:

```
from Crypto.Util import asn1
```

The raw stacktrace is listed here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vmagent/python_vm_runtime/google/appengine/ext/vmruntime/meta_app.py", line 550, in GetUserAppAndServe
    app, mod_file = self.GetUserApp(script)
  File "/home/vmagent/python_vm_runtime/google/appengine/ext/vmruntime/meta_app.py", line 411, in GetUserApp
    app = _AppFrom27StyleScript(script)
  File "/home/vmagent/python_vm_runtime/google/appengine/ext/vmruntime/meta_app.py", line 271, in _AppFrom27StyleScript
    app, filename, err = wsgi.LoadObject(script)
  File "/home/vmagent/python_vm_runtime/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/home/vmagent/app/main.py", line 22, in <module>
    import firebase_helper
  File "/home/vmagent/app/firebase_helper.py", line 20, in <module>
    from Crypto.Util import asn1
ImportError: No module named Crypto.Util
```

Now, pycrypto is already included in the app.yaml:

```
libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: 2.7.11
- name: pycrypto
  version: 2.6.1
```

I have SSH'd into the server, and Crypto is installed. I can also load it into a python console on the VM, without problems.

Any idea why I get this error during deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Google App engine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating-an-existing-app), the libraries section of app.yaml is no longer supported in flexible VM. You will need to declare dependencies in requirements.txt.

So, you need to add this line to your `requirements.txt` :

```
pycrypto==2.6.1
```

Make sure you delete the `libraries` directive from your app.yaml

Make sure your runtime is set to `runtime: python-compat`.

Delete the appengine_cfg.py file, since the flexible vm automatically installs all dependencies in the `requirements.txt`.

Comment: The compat runtime may not be necessary but otherwise perfect. :)